# CSS - mask an obj with another

Tags: css

I'm pass long time to try clip: rect and clip-path
But I didn't succeed to do what I want.
I have 2 rectangular div with a background color with alpha.
They move with transition and js.
And when one is behind and other I don't want they overlay each other. 
I would like to do as the right part of the image instead of the left part using a mask.

Could I set my first div as a mask for the second one ?

[image: I want to do some thing like the right part of the image]

edit:
here a quick example of code the clip is on the first div but I would like to make it apply only on the second div

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1vw;
}

.obj {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="obj" style="width: 10vw; height: 3vw; top: 5vw;"></div>
  <div class="obj" style="width: 3vw; height: 10vw; left: 1vw; clip: rect(0,2vw,10vw,0);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show some code, share your progress

Comment: Would you be willing to have the background have a fixed width? It could still be responsive and just hide the overflow.

Comment: The 2 div can move an change of size and sometimes they don't overlay each other.